# How to add locations and distances to a custom layout android

Tags: android, list, sorting, location

I am making an android app that will list specific places that are not on google places. I have all the latitude and longitudes and place names and they will not be changing. I can display them in my custom list and it works fine the problem is I want to sort them all by distance from your(the users) location and display the distance next to them.

I have tried lots of different ways but have become a bit stuck. I would like to say that I am new to programming and sort of stumbling my way through this app, If anyone could help it would be really    appreciated.

So the question im asking is how can/should I sort locations by distance so I can add them to my custom list.

```
// create array to hold place names to be looped through later
    String[] placenames = { "place1", "place2",
            "place3", "place4" };

// // create arrays to hold all the latitudes and longitudes
    double[] latArray = new double[] { 51.39649, 51.659775, 51.585433,
            51.659775 };
    double[] lngArray = new double[] { 0.836523, 0.539901, 0.555385,
            0.539901, };

// hard code my location for test purposes only
    Location MyLocation = new Location("My location");
    MyLocation.setLatitude(51.659775);
    MyLocation.setLongitude(0.539901);

    for (int i = 0; i < placenames.length;) {

// Place location object
        Location PlaceName = new Location(placenames[i]);
        PlaceName.setLatitude(latArray[i]);
        PlaceName.setLongitude(lngArray[i]);
        i++;

// calculate distance in meters
        float distanceInMeters = PlaceName.distanceTo(MyLocation);

// convert to double

        double DistanceInMiles = distanceInMeters * 0.000621371;

        dimint = (int) DistanceInMiles;

// format numbers to two decimal places
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        dim = df.format(DistanceInMiles);

//make treemap and then sortedmap to sort places by distance

        TreeMap<Integer, String> treemap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

        SortedMap<Integer, String> treemapsorted = new TreeMap<Integer,String>();

        treemap.put(dimint, PlaceName.getProvider());

        treemapsorted = treemap.subMap(0, 5);

// Toast for test purpose to see if sort is working

        Toast tst = Toast.makeText(this, treemapsorted.entrySet()
                .toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        tst.show();

        CustomList place_data[] = new CustomList[] {

// This is the problem part 

        new CustomList(R.drawable.picture1, treemapsorted.get(dimint)),

        };

        CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,
                R.layout.listview_item_row, place_data);
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reviewed your code and found lots of problems:

1. Use `i++` in your for loop statement instead of in the loop body, like this:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < placenames.length; i++) {

   }
   ```
2. You calculate the distance in miles, cast this to int (I would use `Math.round()` here) and then create a string with DecimalFormat which you don't use.
3. You create a TreeMap in every loop iteration. Move the creation in front of the loop and add items to it in the loop body.
4. `TreeMap` is not the right class for this task. I tested your code and the Map contained only 3 items after the loop. The reason is, that a TreeMap contains key value pairs, where the key has to be unique. Adding an element with a key (distance in your case), which is already in the map, results in overwriting that element. So instead of a `TreeMap` I recommend using an `ArrayList`. You need to create a class with all the variables you need, like distance and place name. This class needs to implement the interface `Comparable<Class>`. You will then have to implement the method `public int compareTo(T other)` in which you compare the distance with the distance of the other object. Then you can sort the ArrayList using `Collections.sort(arrayList)`. In the for loop body you should add items to that ArrayList, then sort it, then iterate over the ArrayList items and add them to your `ListView`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have no idea why I put the i++ outside of the loop but thanks for spotting it. I used an ArrayList as you suggested the app is working now. Thanks again for your quick response.